# How can I easily display the dimensions of the text body?

Tags: dimensions

I want to design an image filling the whole page using Illustrator, with the right dpi and dimensions. To accomplish this, I need to know the precise dimensions of the text body (Numbers 7 and 8 in the image below). How can I easily accomplish this? I could of course just subtract the borders from the page dimensions, but is there another way, e. g. a package which does that?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the package `layout` or `layouts`: See: http://www.ctan.org/topic/layout-show

Comment: They are available as `\textwidth` and `\textheight`: if you type `\the\textwidth` and `\the\textheight` in your document, LaTeX will print their values in points; the conversions are 72.27pt=1in or 28.45276pt=1cm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to display the values in millimeters?

Comment: @biologue Yes, it's possible.  See this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181049/how-to-show-margin-distances-in-mm?noredirect=1#comment422161_181049

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `xlayouts` beta. It is available at [github](https://github.com/yannisl/xlayouts).

[image]

If you latex the `xlayouts.dtx` it provides a number of MWE.